# How to move a copied worksheet to the first position?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to copy an Excel worksheet in Python using `openpyxl`. However, it defaults to placing the copied worksheet at the end. I want it at the front. The `copy_worksheet` doesn't allow specifying the position, unlike `create_sheet`. I'd rather not have to recreate the template.

I've considered sorting the sheets, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Suppose I have a file called `number.xlsx` with an existing worksheet titled "blank" that I want to copy.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime

n = float(input("Number: "))

today = datetime.now()
m = today.month
d = today.day
y = str(today.year)

wb = load_workbook('number.xlsx')

if y in wb.sheetnames:
    ws = wb[y]
    ws.cell(row = 2 + d, column = 1 + m).value = n
    wb.save('number.xlsx')

else:
    ws = wb.copy_worksheet(wb["blank"]) #I want the copied sheet at the front, not the back
    ws.title = y
    ws.cell(row = 2 + d, column = 1 + m).value = n
    wb.save('number.xlsx')
```

Comment: FWIW `wb.create_sheet()` lets you set the position of a new worksheet in a workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an example

wb._sheets is what you use to control the order of tabs/sheets.
Get the position of sheet you want to rearrange and modify the list of sheets with new positions.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb=Workbook()
# wb.create_sheet("Sheet")
wb.create_sheet("Sheet2")
wb.create_sheet("Sheet3")
wb.create_sheet("SheetA")
wb.create_sheet("ASheet")
wb.create_sheet("blank")
wb.save('book_original.xlsx')
blank_sheet_position = wb.worksheets.index(wb['blank'']) #get position of new sheet
blank_sheet_new_position = 0 #position where you want to move
sheets = wb._sheets.copy()
sheets.insert(blan_sheet_new_position, sheets.pop(blank_sheet_position))) #modifying the sheets list
wb._sheets = sheets
wb.save('book_myorder.xlsx')
```

Comment: I don't know how many sheets there are or there will be.

Comment: You don't need to know.  all you need to do is manipulate your wb index list . You can get the index of your sheet wb.worksheets.index(wb['blank'']). workbook.worksheets contains a list of worksheet objects. len(workbook.worksheets) will give you total sheets.

Comment: Thank you! The new_sheets line in your answer produced a NoneType, so I just got rid of it and it worked. (wb._sheets = sheets instead)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `move_sheet(sheet, offset=0)` method for this. Here offset calculated as "current sheet index" + offset. Copy worksheet will add the sheet to the last of the workbook. So you need to give negative value to move sheet to index 0.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
    
wb = load_workbook("text.xlsx")
ws = wb.copy_worksheet(wb["sample"])
ws.title = "NewNameForCopiedSheet"
wb.move_sheet("NewNameForCopiedSheet", -(len(wb.sheetnames)-1))
```