# How do I move (reorder) sheets in Excel file with Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, xlwt

There is an excel file named `test.xlsx`, which has 3 sheets: ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'], how do I use Python to reorder the sheets as: ['Sheet3', 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2']

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move a copied worksheet to the first position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404342/how-to-move-a-copied-worksheet-to-the-first-position)

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks have the `move_sheet()` method.

Comment: Can you post the entire code?

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You can easily look this up.